# More friendly dashboard access denied message perhaps?

Tags: wordpress, dashboard, user-account, user-dashboard, user-experience

It is Wordpress page and Civi dashboard inserted via the shortcode`[civicrm component="user-dashboard" hijack="1"]`
There are 3 components available at the "Display Preferences":  Contributions, Memberships, Events.
We've spotted expired Members get  the "Sorry, due to an error..." message trying to access the page.  How would you made this message more kind and user-friendly? Maybe even for Anonymous users?

**UPD** Thanks to @Coleman we seems to be having an alternative. The new User Dashboard extension is in early development therefore doesn't have a documentation yet, especially regarding permission settings. Currently it still displays the "Access Denied" page  if a membership expires.

[image]

---

```
 Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill 
 your request at the moment. 
 You may want to contact your administrator or service provider 
 with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
 You do not have permission to access this page.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the new Dashboard extension (`cv en user_dashboard`) which uses SearchKit & FormBuilder & is more customizable.

New Dashboard settings are here /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsearch#/list?tab=packaged

You may want to unlock the results via "Bypass Permissions" button ( see attached grab ) even if you have all permissions granted.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, updated the question.

Comment: Spoke too soon: this does not work for Expired Memberships, it still displays the "Access Denied" page.